# Are there any server commands to despawn neutral mobs in Minecraft 1.6.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After a rather too succesful experiment with an infinite villager spawner in Minecraft 1.6.4, our server is now overrun by masses (hundreds, if not thousands) of villagers.

Is there a server command, or other simple solution, for despawning such a huge number of mobs?

Since they are neutral/friendly, switching to Peaceful mode is not an option. They are in a sealed off room I can't get close to (due to a literal 0.1 FPS around the zone), so using TNT or Lava isn't exactly possible either.

Comment: Is it a bukkit server? Have you plugins installed? Like essentials or worldedit?

Comment: I'm playing the Yogscast Complete pack from the ATLauncher. I'm not entirely sure, but it does seem to be a bukkit server.